# The logcat output uninformative when Kivy app stops on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am using kivy v1.10.1, buildozer 0.39 and python 3.5.2 on Ubuntu.

I have a very basic kivy app

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.uix.button import Label
from kivy.lang import Builder

root = Builder.load_string('''
<MainFrame>:
    Label:
        text: 'Hello world'
''')

class MainFrame(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainFrame, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class BasicApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainFrame()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    BasicApp().run()
```

The buildozer spec includes:

```
requirements = python3, kivy
```

I can build the APK with buildozer, but when I run it on the android device it seems to load, but then stops.

This seems to be the relevant part of the logcat output

```
-31 12:18:56.281  7803  7803 D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=53
08-31 12:18:56.282  3620  4975 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{e85acd2d0 u0 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
08-31 12:18:56.282  3620  4975 D WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: e85acd2 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)
08-31 12:18:56.282  3620  4975 W InputDispatcher: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel
08-31 12:18:56.283 30622 30622 D [WeatherWidget(15503)]  DB L2: {[610591C4E30FED4A153FF198DAC84EFEE3319B0D622FD4A19809E90ED3C1398368D658B139FCCB8B9564F5B4E9CB634EAEB5D3DD5DDD4E73700B72505132108E]}
08-31 12:18:56.284 30622 30622 D [WeatherWidget(15503)]  : {[E9BDC1AC9F9B078A92B3F309630276C89F9B6E52C087A495B97355481F2FDE5B58A757A09967AB7BD9E1187CEA5BB356FACBD4A552A7402C88647F970C513A69]}
08-31 12:18:56.284  3620  7254 I ActivityManager: Process org.test.myapp (pid 30399) has died(75,351)
08-31 12:18:56.285  3620  7254 D ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 30399
08-31 12:18:56.285  3620  4975 D InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 30399
08-31 12:18:56.285  3620  4975 D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=549
08-31 12:18:56.286  3620  7254 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{74325c3d0 u0 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t14282}: app died, no saved state
08-31 12:18:56.286  3620  4975 D InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=549
08-31 12:18:56.286  3620  4975 D InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=624
08-31 12:18:56.286 30642 30666 I DatabaseManager: [#CMH#] createTables  
08-31 12:18:56.286  3620  4975 D WindowManager: openInputChannel mInputChannel: e85acd2 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)
08-31 12:18:56.287  3620  4975 D InputDispatcher: Focus entered window: 30399
08-31 12:18:56.287  3620  5346 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{d2e042ad0 u0 SurfaceView - org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
08-31 12:18:56.290  3620  7254 W MultiScreenManagerService: moveTaskBackToDisplayIfNeeded(): root is not base activity
08-31 12:18:56.294 30642 30666 I CloudEventSyncTable: [#CMH#]  CloudEventSyncTable constructor  
08-31 12:18:56.295 30642 30666 I EventSyncCacheTable: [#CMH#]  EventSyncBackUpTable constructor  
08-31 12:18:56.295 30642 30666 I DatabaseManager: [#CMH#] DB init done ReadOnly:  false
08-31 12:18:56.295 30642 30666 I Controller: [#CMH#] ServicesSetValue =      41881406
08-31 12:18:56.297  3620  7254 D GameManagerService: there is not sem_perfomance_mode on setting
08-31 12:18:56.301 30642 30666 I Controller: [#CMH#] storagepermisssion =      0
08-31 12:18:56.301 30642 30666 I Controller: [#CMH#] initializeBroadcastReceiver  com.samsung.cmh.database.DatabaseManager@8c4b3c8
08-31 12:18:56.302 30642 30666 I SystemBroadcastReceiver: [#CMH#]  in initialize  
08-31 12:18:56.302 30642 30666 I SystemBroadcastReceiver: [#CMH#] SystemBroadcastReceiver 
08-31 12:18:56.307  3620  5346 I WindowManager_SurfaceController: Destroying surface Surface(name=SurfaceView - org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2906 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:1120 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1880 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2924 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowLocked:2864 com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied:2320 android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice:701 <bottom of call stack> 
08-31 12:18:56.308  3072  7256 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1073 Removed QythonActiv (4/12)
08-31 12:18:56.308  3072  3134 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1074 Removed QythonActiv (3/11)
08-31 12:18:56.308  3072  3134 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1073 Removed QythonActiv (-2/11)
08-31 12:18:56.308  3072  3134 I SurfaceFlinger: id=1074 Removed QythonActiv (-2/11)
08-31 12:18:56.326  3620  7254 D InputDispatcher: Focus left window: 30399
08-31 12:18:56.327  3620  7254 D WindowManager: disposeInputChannel mInputChannel: e85acd2 org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (server)
08-31 12:18:56.327  3620  7254 D InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=624
08-31 12:18:56.346  3620  7254 I WindowManager_SurfaceController: Destroying surface Surface(name=org.test.myapp/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2906
```

The full logcat text is at:

https://justpaste.it/7hge7

Can anyone please point me to the possible source of the problem?

Comment: Post the full lgocat output from between when your app is started and when it crashes. You can also strip out only the lines containing the string `python` to narrow down the search.

Comment: @inclement I have pasted the logcat output at https://justpaste.it/7hge7

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any clear error there - it looks like there are issues loading libpython2.7.so, but this shouldn't even be happening. Could you paste the full logcat without limiting to lines containing `python`? This may be a lower level issue where we have to care about stuff other than the python process itself.

Comment: @inclement here is the full logcat http://ge.tt/2CRlJrx2

Comment: Odd that it is trying to load libpython2.7. Could you post your `buildozer.spec` file?

Comment: @johnAnderson it's in the same location http://ge.tt/2CRlJrx2

Answer (score 0):

The actual traceback in the logcat is this part:

```
08-31 14:29:28.636 29017 29035 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
08-31 14:29:28.636 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 21, in <module>
08-31 14:29:28.637 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/app.py", line 829, in run
08-31 14:29:28.637 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 18, in build
08-31 14:29:28.638 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 14, in __init__
08-31 14:29:28.638 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/relativelayout.py", line 265, in __init__
08-31 14:29:28.639 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/floatlayout.py", line 65, in __init__
08-31 14:29:28.639 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/layout.py", line 76, in __init__
08-31 14:29:28.639 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 361, in __init__
08-31 14:29:28.640 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 469, in apply_class_lang_rules
08-31 14:29:28.640 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 538, in apply
08-31 14:29:28.641 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/lang/builder.py", line 654, in _apply_rule
08-31 14:29:28.641 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 188, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__cinit__
08-31 14:29:28.641 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 447, in kivy.properties.Property.link
08-31 14:29:28.642 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 632, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.init_storage
08-31 14:29:28.642 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 418, in kivy.properties.Property.init_storage
08-31 14:29:28.642 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 655, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.convert
08-31 14:29:28.643 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 663, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_str
08-31 14:29:28.643 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 670, in kivy.properties.NumericProperty.parse_list
08-31 14:29:28.643 29017 29035 I python  :    File "kivy/properties.pyx", line 296, in kivy.properties.dpi2px
08-31 14:29:28.644 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/utils.py", line 505, in __get__
08-31 14:29:28.645 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/kivy/metrics.py", line 162, in dpi
08-31 14:29:28.645 29017 29035 I python  :    File "/home/jeff/projects/basic_kivy_app/.buildozer/android/platform/build/build/python-installs/myapp/jnius/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
08-31 14:29:28.646 29017 29035 I python  :  ImportError: dlopen failed: library "libpython2.7.so" not found
08-31 14:29:28.646 29017 29035 I python  : Python for android ended.
```

I don't know what's causing this. It looks like pyjnius is linked against python2.7, but I don't see why that would be the case (and p4a should specifically take care of it not happening). Is this the first build you've attempted? Does the same thing happen if you clean everything and run again?

Comment: Yes. That fixed it. I deleted the .buildozer folder and it's OK. I guess there must have been some crud floating about

Answer (score 0):

Th problem was resolved by deleting the .buildozer folder and starting again.

I think I had previously had the line:

```
requirements = python2, kivy
```

in the buildozer.spec and when I was getting problems I had changed it to:

```
 requirements = python3, kivy
```

but did not delete the .buildozer folder.

This had presumably caused the problems covered in the question.

I include this answer to encourage others who might be encountering similar problems to delete the .buildozer folder and start with a clean build before asking for help. I should have thought of that before.